# GL_INVALID_VALUE from GLUtils.texImage2D

Tags: java, android, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to develop a small game for Android using OpenGLES2.0, and I have this issue that stops me from achieving compatibility between devices. I'm testing my app in two devices, an Xperia Z1 and a Galaxy S2 (as the emulator does not work with OpenGLES2.0). If I call `GLUtils.texImage2D` to load a texture with a Bitmap that came from an image of resolution lower or equal to 1024x1024 it works fine in both devices. Using a texture of 2048x2048 works on the S2, but no longer does on the Z1 (it returns `GL_INVALID_VALUE`). Loading anything higher than that does not work in the Z1, nor in the S2. However, I already checked `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, and in both devices it is set to 4096. I do not know what is wrong, I call texImage2D as follows:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1,texture,0);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.test);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question as I already found out what was wrong. As I'm in early stages of android development, I put all my textures in the `drawable` folder. Android auto scales this images depending on the dpi of the device, and Xperia Z1 has a 441dpi screen, against the 217dpi of the Galaxy S2, resulting in a larger factor for the resize, reaching the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` limit with a smaller texture when creating the bitmap. I'm using the `drawable-nodpi` folder now and it works, but I'll learn more about this.